# How to enable remote trigger in jenkins file for a pipeline job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

[image]How to enable the "Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)" section in a Jenkins file for a pipeline job. Want to achieve the same task of freestyle project in pipeline.

Comment: I want to know the answer as well :( dud jenkins sucks so much, why is this not easy to find??

Comment: Hi @matheuscscp, we couldn't overcome the same via the Jenkins file but we created a workaround and created an intermediate job in the same jenkins server, which triggers the pipeline job.

Answer (score 2):

I found this for a declarative pipeline, which doesn't work on my version of Jenkins, but I think that is because I have an older installation.

```
pipeline{
  triggers{ RemoteBuildTrigger(remoteBuildToken: 'mysecret') }
}
```

[Source](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jenkins-declarative-pipeline)

Answer (score -3):

Jenkins Pipeline job also provides the same option for remote build trigger.  There is no need for additional plugins or workarounds.
[image]

Jenkins jobs can also be triggered by user level authentication tokens. To enable user level authentication token please follow below steps.

1. Log in to Jenkins.
2. Click you name (Upper-right corner).
3. Click Configure (Left-side menu).
4. Use "Add new Token" button to generate a new one then name it.
   Note: You must copy the token when you generate it, You cannot view the token afterwards.
5. Revoke old tokens when no longer needed.

Comment: The question was about how to enable via Pipeline syntax, read the question pls